# Is there any reason politicians don't talk about internal affairs while abroad?

Tags: media, international-relations

I've read a news article where my president (of Portugal) is interviewed while in the UN headquarters and, when asked about a judicial investigation in course in my country, he told that he will not comment that "while out of Portugal".

This attitude of don't talk about internal affairs while abroad is something politicians made for some specific reason, or may be simply a sort of trick to avoid the question? If that is a common behavior, what is the reason?

Comment: This is far from universal. Spanish PMs do often talk about internal affairs while abroad; sometimes refering to the host country policies. For example a day or two ago Spanish PM was comparing Catalonia to Quebec while in Canada. Some opinion piece I did read a long time ago told that it was due to the media sending abroad (in the PM's plane) the same reporters that did cover the government locally, so the reporters did ask about the subjects they were familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

It is somewhat common, I would say.

The tradition is that both the government and (when applicable) the opposition look out for the best interest of the country while abroad, above "petty" party politics. If one accepts that, then it would be "unfair" by government representatives abroad to interfere with domestic political debates. After all, any reply by the opposition would undercut a representative of the country abroad.

Within Europe that is somewhat fraying with the slow development of effective European political parties. But that does not apply in New York.